# MySQL filesort on GROUP BY YEAR & Month

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by

I have a large table that stores debug information for my web app. The issue is that the table is now 500,000 rows and one of the queries is slow because the index isn't being used.

SQL:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) AS `count`, month(event_date) AS `month`, year(event_date) AS `year`FROM events WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY year(event_date) DESC, month(event_date) DESC LIMIT 6;
```

Result:

```
SIMPLE  events  index   NULL    event_date  8   NULL    139358  Using index; Using temporary; Using file sort
```

And here is the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Event Primary Key',
`event_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'User ID',
`server_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The ID of the remote log client',
`remote_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The Event Primary Key from the remote client',
`event_date` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Event Datetime in local timezone',
`event_date_utc` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Event Datetime in UTC timezone',
`event_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The type of event',
`event_source` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Text description of the source of the event',
`event_severity` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Notice, Warning etc',
`event_file` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'The full file location of the source of the event',
`event_file_line` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The line in the file that triggered the event',
`event_ip_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'IP Address of the user that triggered the event',
`event_summary` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'A summary of the description',
`event_description` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Full description of the event',
`event_trace` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Full PHP trace',
`event_synced` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `event_type` (`event_type`),
KEY `event_source` (`event_source`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `server_id` (`server_id`),
KEY `event_date` (`event_date`)
)
```

If anyone has any ideas on getting the same results without a file sort that would be awesome!

Answer (score 4):

GROUP BY implies ORDER BY in MySQL

So try adding ORDER BY NULL: this usually eliminates a filesort

See ["ORDER BY Optimization"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html) in the MySQL docs

Comment: Thanks for this. The ORDER BY NULL does seem to remove the file sort, so that is a big improvement.

Comment: Just an update. This still seems to be causing temporary tables to generate the result, meaning my key cache needs to be as large as the results being returned.

This plus WHERE event_date > SUBDATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) helps a lot, but it is still not has fast as I would like it to be on the current hardware setup.

Again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your key problem is that you are specifying no `WHERE` clause.  Your use of `WHERE 1=1` is pointless.  The problem is that you are trying to get the `YEAR` and `MONTH` from MySQL without limiting the number of rows, and therefore it processes MONTH(..) and YEAR(...) for each row before it is able to process the GROUP.

The fact it still isn't using the INDEX after my earlier suggestion indicates you have more to your query than you are letting on, if that's the case please let me know and I can help you more easily.  Otherwise, I would recommend checking below (though I'm having to guess at your purposes as you haven't stated what you are trying to achieve)

If you are after the last 6 calendar months specifically then the following would also help significantly.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS `count`, 
    MONTH(event_date) AS `month`, 
    YEAR(event_date) AS `year`
FROM events
-- Get the first day of this month, and subtract 6 months
WHERE event_date > SUBDATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY `year` DESC, `month` DESC;
```

If you have additional WHERE criteria though, that would change the advice given so if that's the case please update

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to improve the speed at all.


    EXPLAIN SELECT count( id ) AS `count` , MONTH( event_date ) AS `month` , YEAR( event_date ) AS `year`
FROM EVENTS WHERE 1 =1
GROUP BY `year` DESC , `month` DESC
LIMIT 6

Result: Using temporary; Using file sort.

Comment: First of all, the `WHERE 1=1` is not needed.  Secondly I'll revise my answer, however your key problem is the lack of WHERE to limit the number of rows, so it needs to query the entire database before it can reorder it, group it, and get the top 6 rows.  If you have any WHERE syntax (as your continued use of `WHERE 1=1` suggests) please can you post it up - it'll make giving relevant advice far easier.

Comment: Hi Simon,
Yes there is some filtering (WHERE) on event_type and event_source.

Limiting the returned rows by using SUBDATE as you suggested has helped. The ORDER BY NULL doesn't actually seem to help much, I thought it did but when I tried it on the larger database there are still issues.

Basically what you're saying is that I cannot do this query on indexes alone? The table is about 300mbyte in size. To improve performance I really need to increase the MySQL key buffer cache size.

It seems a bit odd as the query is pretty simple.

Comment: The query is pretty simple, however the number of rows required can grow pretty large.  By limiting the number of rows it's able to instantly skip processing on any outside that range hence the performance increase.  The ORDER BY syntax is irrelevant as it'd still have needed to process all rows to figure out the latest 6 if you don't specify the limit.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others have posted:

If you run an `EXPLAIN SELECT...`  and MySQL reports that it uses no index for that query (or not the one you want), you could solve this by querying the data with `SELECT... FORCE INDEX...`. For more details about the syntax of this, look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using SELECT * which means select all rows so the whole table is scanned - try selecting specific rows to show
2. Also there are no parameters to filter the data so the whole table is read and returned, try restricting either by date or some other parameter